# How to hide number of every chapter?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to hide the number of every chapter in my thesis when I use command `\chapter`. But the thing is when I put `*` such that `\chapter*`, the subsection will be start from 0.1. So, I want to hide the number at front of word chapter but still the number at section below start with 1.1 and so on. here my latex command;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, footskip=1.2cm, left=4cm, right=2.2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}%set page numbering at bottom
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 



\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter 1}

I want hide the number at front of word chapter but still the number at section below start with 1

\section{bab 1}

blah 

\chapter{ chapter 2}

\section{sub chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

here the output:

[image: my output]

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't want to write `\chapter{CHAPTER 1}`  in your real rocument, right?

Comment: Where can e find `thesis.cls`? I have a lot of experience with various `thesis.cls` and `Thesis.cls`, none of which was a good one.

Comment: Does the class load pacage `titlesec`? If not, load it by yourself and use `titleformat` in your preamble. A similar question was asked yesterday, [but in german](http://golatex.de/falsche-nummerierung-mit-chapter-t18480.html).

Comment: Before i forget it, welcome to TeX.SX :-)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to make `\chapter` be like `\chapter*` with the addition of some counter and ToC updating. To do this, add

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store \chapter in \oldchapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{% Update \chapter
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}% Step chapter counter
  \oldchapter*{#1}% Regular \chapter*
  \chaptermark{#1}% Set chapter mark (typically for header)
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}% Add chapter to ToC
}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Would it be worth to update the headers as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Of course!